# How can I send a put request with JWT Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm trying to send a put request on my local API. I'm using JWT interceptor and it works fine with POST, GET and DELETE requests, but doesn't work with PUT, it is unauthorized.

I console.log a GET and PUT requests, both of them shows that the token is right there on header.

#### PUT Request

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/2",
  "body": "",
  "reportProgress": false,
  "withCredentials": false,
  "responseType": "json",
  "method": "PUT",
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": [{
      "name": "Authorization",
      "value": "JWT Token",
      "op": "s"
    }],
    "headers": {},
    "lazyInit": {
      "normalizedNames": {},
      "lazyUpdate": null
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "updates": null,
    "cloneFrom": null,
    "encoder": {},
    "map": {}
  },
  "urlWithParams": "http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/2"
}
```

#### GET Request

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/api/me",
  "body": null,
  "reportProgress": false,
  "withCredentials": false,
  "responseType": "json",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": [{
      "name": "Authorization",
      "value": "JWT Token",
      "op": "s"
    }],
    "headers": {},
    "lazyInit": {
      "normalizedNames": {},
      "lazyUpdate": null,
      "headers": {}
    }
  },
  "params": {
    "updates": null,
    "cloneFrom": null,
    "encoder": {},
    "map": {}
  },
  "urlWithParams": "http://localhost:8080/api/me"
}
```

#### My service to send put request

```
  updateSchedule(id): Observable<any>{
    let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUservalue;

    const httpOptions = {      
      headers:  new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': `${currentUser.token}`
    })
  };
    return this.http.put(`${this._url}/tasks/${id}`, httpOptions)
  }
```

#### The 401 error

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/2 401 (Unauthorized)
```

How can I validate this JWT on PUT request?

Comment: Please use text instead of images to show data. An easy way is to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(objectToObserve))`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpOptions is the third parameter, second must be body. Put an empty string if there is no body. See here https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request

```
return this.http.put(`${this._url}/tasks/${id}`,'', httpOptions)
```

Comment: It still returns 401 unauthorized, I tried this way. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Instead of putting a empty string, I inputted "null" and it worked